# How to transfer the data from my production DB to my staging DB in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, pg

I'm trying to transfer the data from my production DB to my staging DB without success.

I'm following heroku's documentation on it: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#transfers

These are the commands I've run...

```
$ heroku addons:add pgbackups --remote staging
$ heroku addons:add pgbackups --remote production
$ heroku pgbackups:capture --remote production
$ heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --remote production` --remote staging
```

And this is the message I get...

```
Usage: heroku pgbackups:restore [<DATABASE> [BACKUP_ID|BACKUP_URL]]

restore a backup to a database

if no DATABASE is specified, defaults to DATABASE_URL and latest backup
if DATABASE is specified, but no BACKUP_ID, defaults to latest backup
```

It seems I'm spelling something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

I've also tried the same command using the name of the apps instead of the remote...

```
$ heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp` --app myapp-staging
```

But I get the same message with no actual transfer going on.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you've captured correctly.  Always use `--app` instead of `--remote`

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture --app myapp
$ heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp` --app myapp-staging
```

Comment: Thanks Neil. I've just tried that and I'm getting a `! Resource not found` error. I've also run `heroku pgbackups --app myapp` and it's correctly showing me my backups so the resource is there, it just doesn't load it.

Comment: `resource not found` is usually returned when you use an incorrect app name - these should be as listed on the myapps page on heroku site. Neils command is exactly correct as I've just used it myself.

Comment: Thanks John, I swear I'm using the right names though. I've just double checked that running `heroku apps`

Comment: Are you sure you're authenticating as the correct user for the apps in question - I have several accounts and this always catches me out...

Comment: you should try https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts - it makes dealing with multiple accounts and heroku so much better!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if Heroku's changed since these were posted last January, but when I run

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp` --app myapp-staging
```

I kept getting an error that just said

> "!    Backup not found"

Even though, when I ran the command by itself to get the URL:

```
heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp
```

and then tried the URL out in the browser, that URL WAS correct.

So instead I just tried sending the copied/pasted URL to the command instead, like:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE "http://urlgoeshere" --app myapp-staging
```

I had to use DOUBLE quotes around the URL, not SINGLE quotes.  Otherwise I got this error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   'Expires' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. 'Signature' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and pasting the URL as Gayle says worked for me.

Comment: Someone commented on our Dev Center that they've run into the same thing, but I haven't been able to replicate this issue. Can you tell me what error you were seeing (if anything more than the "! Backup not found" above), if you still see the issue, what happens when you run `set -x` beforehand (run `set +x` afterward to turn off echo again) and what shell and OS you are using (I'm with Heroku Postgres)?